# Checking the identity of a character in a string at a specific position

Tags: string, position, character

I wrote the simple amateurish code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# this code reads a string from a file
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

    c = data[3]
    if c == ["a"]:   
        print c
    else:
        print (c, 'is not a')
```

As I wrote the string in the text1.txt file, I knew for a fact that the character at position [3] is indeed ['a']. However, the code returns the impertinent answer:

('a', 'is not a')

I tried many things: converting the string into a list, using "is" instead of "==", adding or not adding citation marks to "a", but the result is always the same: the code fails to establish identity. What is going on here?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing against a list in the if statement. It should be:

```
if c == "a":   
    print c
else:
    print (c, 'is not a')
```